# magmi : I need to import (and assign) 7000+ attribute_code Values through csv

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import, magmi

magmi : I need to import (and assign) 7000+ attribute_code Values through csv.
My issue is that the format of magmi csv is Attribute names should be horizontaly column wise(7000+ cols) and values should be under.

I need to do it same like pivot or Is there is a better solution?.

Note: my data is originally stored in MS-SQL db

Comment: Can you put screen shot of your file for example just with 2-3 product data.

Comment: Here is the screen shot https://ibb.co/i1qL5e,   I want column2 data horizontally, and column3 as it's values that means column1 will not be repeated, and I will have only two lines from the above data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the issue from the MS-SQL side.
You have use Pivot Query for an unknown number of columns using STUFF Function also solved my issue,

Here is the query I did:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(AttrName) 
                from Attribute_View
                group by AttrName
                order by AttrName
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT sku,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select sku, AttrName, AttrValue
            from Attribute_View
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(AttrValue)
            for AttrName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
```